# Deleting String using sed

Tags: unix, sed, scripting

I am trying to delete a SPECIFIC string on a file using `sed`.

`test.txt` contains

```
123
456
789
111
1
000136
```

For example i need to remove only the `1` text in the file. I tried to use the command

```
sed '/1/d' test.txt
```

the output will be

```
456
789
```

How can i only delete `1` using sed? Is there any way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your example is, that the pattern used in `sed` matches all lines containing a `1` character.

Adjust the pattern instead: `sed '/^1$/d' test.txt`

This will match only lines containing a *single character*, namely `1`.

This would not match lines containing extra whitespace!

Read more about regular expressions (and the special characters `^` and `$`) at: 
https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Comment: Hi. Thank you! Got it